# Attach a function to every last element of dynamic content

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

I'm having trouble attaching a function to every nth element, one time, for each element.

The idea is to trigger an ajax call whenever the last element comes into view. There's a handy jquery plugin called [inview](https://github.com/protonet/jquery.inview) that I'm using.

I have a list of 10 posts structured like so:

**HTML**

```
<div id="sglsPosts">
    <nav>
        <div class="sglsPostContainer"></div>
        <div class="sglsPostContainer"></div>
        <div class="sglsPostContainer"></div>
        <div class="sglsPostContainer"></div>
        <div class="sglsPostContainer"></div>
        <div class="sglsPostContainer"></div>
    </nav>
</div>
```

At first I was trying to do this with something like `$('div nav > div:nth-child(10n)')` but then thought there's no need as all I want is the last element so I ended up using:
`var elem = $('.sglsPostContainer:last-child');`

**I then want to attach a function to whichever is the last element, before and after I load more via an ajax call.**

I understand using `jQuery.on();` is the function I should be using for applying functions to dynamic content, and I only want to do the function once, so I started off with this:

**jQuery**

```
var elem = $('.sglsPostContainer:last-child');
elem.on('inview', function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.one('inview', function (event, isInView) {
        if (isInView) {
            console.log('hello');
            $this.unbind('inview');
        }
    });
});
```

So far so good, it appeared to be working, now to add the ajax stuff.

I'm going to call 10 posts and append them to `$('#sglsPosts nav')`, then whenever the last element comes into view I want to trigger the ajax call again.

For this to work properly I need to unbind the event that *was* the last element and bind the event to *new* last element, I was hoping `jQuery.one();` and `$this.unbind('inview');` would take care of that, but alas here I am.

**jQuery**

```
var elem = $('.sglsPostContainer:last-child');
elem.on('inview', function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.one('inview', function (event, isInView) {
        if (isInView) {
            console.log('hello');
            $.ajax({
                dataType: "HTML",
                url: ajax_url,
                type: 'POST',
                data: {
                    action: 'side_scroll'
                },
                success: function (data) {
                    $('#sglsPosts nav').append(data);
                }
            });
            $this.unbind('inview');
        }
    });
});
```

This only triggers the event once, probably because I have unbound the event, I think I need to recalculate which is the last element again *after* the ajax call and after the last element was unbound.

Help appreciated.

**EDIT:ANSWER**.

```
function nth_view() {
    var elem = $('.sglsPostContainer:last-child');
    elem.addClass('nth');
}
nth_view();

var offset = 1;
$('.nth').live('inview', function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    if ($this.hasClass('nth')) {
        $this.removeClass('nth');
        var ajax_url = $('#sglsPosts').attr('data-url');
        offset = parseInt(offset) + 10;
        $.ajax({
            dataType: "HTML",
            url: ajax_url,
            type: 'POST',
            data: {
                action: 'side_scroll',
                offset: offset
            },
            success: function (data) {
                $('#sglsPosts nav').append(data);
                nth_view();
            }
        });
    }
});
});
```

**The main thing here is the function `nth_view()` which gets called on success and instead of removing the function, it was easier just to add and remove a class.**

Comment: Rebind after `$(document).bind('DOMNodeInserted',function(){ ... });`?

Comment: @BradChristie Hi, thanks for the reply. This is the first time I've come across `DOMNodeInserted`, how is this supposed to be implemented?

Comment: that event is fired every time content comes in from an AJAX call (or the DOm is manipulated after-load). So, if you need to keep grabbing `:last-child` that would be the place to rebind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say first execute the unbind, then do you ajax stuff and finally bind it again.
to achive that it might be easier to put the 'inview' function separate and call it x, then you can do something like this:

```
$this.unbind('inview');
$.ajax({
   dataType: "HTML",
   url: ajax_url,
    type: 'POST',
    data: {
       action: 'side_scroll'
     },
      success: function (data) {
           $('#sglsPosts nav').append(data);
           $('.sglsPostContainer:last-child').on('inview', FUNCTION_X_NAME);
       }
  });
```

haven't tested this though..

EDIT: better would be to only unbind/rebind in the success of the ajax call. That way if the ajax stuff fails, you still have the original functionality

Comment: Hey you're basically right, I've almost got it working with a combination of what you said and adding/removing a class when an element comes into view. Thanks.

Comment: you are welcome. Normally I'd write it out a bit better, but it was nearing the end of my work day ;-)